# Can we use CHAR(2) as a primary key in Symfony/Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I know that generally we should use INT as primary key, but in this particular case it would be very helpful for me to use CHAR(2) as PK.

I use MySql, I do understand that it allows it, but what about Symfony with Doctrine? Precisely, using it in an entity.

I could simply test it, but redesigning all those relations to only find out it doesn't work, or even it works, but in a month it will turn out there are some issues with it, seems a bit overkill.

So maybe somebody has an experience with this approach?

Edit: it's not a standalone entity, it has relations.

Comment: You can use [whatever you want](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-id) as PK, though you need to be prepared to populate the value *by hand* if the [provided strategies](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#generatedvalue) do not fit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, if you add this a answer I'll be happy to accept it:)

Comment: I don't think that's good enough to be an answer. But maybe if you implement a solution, you can come back here and post it (including your used strategy). I think that would be more helpful to future readers.